# Is there a faster way to run a class without changing it to the main class?

Tags: java, netbeans

Im learning how to use netbeans and every time I run any class it only runs the main class( for example I have helloworld.java as my main class right now and test.java as another class. but when I try to run test.java it runs helloworld.java since that is the main class). my current solution is every time I want to run a different class I have to go to project properties and manually change it to the main class. Is there a way to do this faster? or a way to do this automatically every time you run a class?

Comment: You can run any Java file directly in Netbeans as long as it has a `main()`. Right-click and see all the options.

Answer (score 1):

You can either right-click on the file in the code editor and select "Run file", or press shift-F6 to run the currently selected file in the editor.